# Switch views in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 views, one is map view, one is grid view of restaurants. I have a toggle to switch between them. Both of them are in the body. I have a javascript function to switch between them below

```
  $(function() {
    $('#map-toggle').change(function(){
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            document.getElementById("restaurants").style.height = "0%";
            document.getElementById("restaurants").style.width = "0%";
            document.getElementById("map").style.height = "100%";
            document.getElementById("map").style.width = "100%";
            getLocation(true);
        }else{
            document.getElementById("map").style.height = "0%";
            document.getElementById("map").style.width = "0%";
            document.getElementById("restaurants").style.height = "100%";
            document.getElementById("restaurants").style.width = "100%";
        }
    })
})
```

The map works fine but the grid view doesn't disappear when I switch to map view. The grid view comes before the map view in the body. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery has `hide()`and `show()`methods:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#map-toggle').change(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('#restaurants').hide();
        $('#map').show();
        getLocation(true);
    }else{
        $('#map').hide();
        $('#restaurants').show();
    }
})})
```

[jQuery Effects - Hide and Show](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works by adding one more line `document.getElementById("map").style.height = "100%";`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggleClass()` or `toggle()` to hide and show elements

```
  $(function() {
    $('#map-toggle').click(function() {
      $("#restaurant").toggleClass('hide')
      $("#map").toggleClass('hide')
    });
  })
```

`class="hide"`can be anything and can have any styles

or

```
  $(function() {
    $('#map-toggle').click(function() {
     $("#restaurant, #map").toggle();
    });
 })
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLt7wcw4/6/)